# How to calculate probability distribution from the given characteristic function?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

I want to calculate the probability distribution from the characteristic function given as

$$G(k) = e^{ik\mu_1 - \frac{\sigma^2 k^2}{2}}$$

The probability distribution is given as inverse Fourier transform of the characteristic function

$$P(x) = \int \frac{dk}{2\pi} e^{-ikx} G(x)$$

I'm stuck in solving this integral. The integral of this results in the Gaussian distribution. Can someone help me out solving this integral?

Comment: $G(x) = e^{ik\mu_1 - \frac{\sigma^2 k^2}{2}}$? Who's $k$, a constant? And sorry, but if a characteristic function is constant, it must be $\equiv1$. Just in case you mean $G(x) = e^{ix\mu_1 - \frac{\sigma^2 x^2}{2}}$: that's the characteristic function of a normal distribution with mean $\mu_1$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Sorry! It is G(k). I edited the question.